# My DatePicker cannot setText() to textView at first try

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I got this problem cause my DatePicker not set text to textView on first try but after first try it can set without any problem.

This is my setDate Function, it will work after click at Linearlayout.

```
public void setBirthDate(){
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog( setting.this,
            datePickerDialog,
            year, month, day);
    dialog.getWindow();
    dialog.show();
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month += 1;
            String date = null;
            if (month < 10) {
                if (day < 10) {
                    date = "0" + day + "/" + "0" + month + "/" + year;
                } else if (day >= 10) {
                    date = day + "/" + "0" + month + "/" + year;
                }
            } else if (month >= 10) {
                if (day < 10) {
                    date = "0" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                } else if (day >= 10) {
                    date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(setting.this, date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textView_birthdate.setText(date);
        }
    };
}
```

And this is how I handle event.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.settinglo_birthdate){
        setBirthDate();
    }
else if(){}
...
...
...
}
```

This is my onCreate

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting_02);
    list_linear = new ArrayList<>();
    list_textview = new ArrayList<>();
    toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.settingtb);
    toolbar.setCollapsible(true);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Setting");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    initialVIew();
}
```

This is initialView() method

```
public void initialVIew(){

    /* layout initial & add to list */
    list_linear.add(linear_fname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_fname));
    list_linear.add(linear_lname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_lname));
    list_linear.add(linear_birthdate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_birthdate));
    list_linear.add(linear_gender = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_gender));
    list_linear.add(linear_tel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_tel));
    list_linear.add(linear_carefname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_c_fname) );
    list_linear.add(linear_carelname = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_c_lname) );
    list_linear.add(linear_careemail = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_c_email) );
    list_linear.add(linear_caretel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_c_tel) );
    list_linear.add(linear_min = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_glucose_min) );
    list_linear.add(linear_max = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settinglo_glucose_max) );

    /* textView initial & add to list */
    list_textview.add(textView_fname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_fname));
    list_textview.add(textView_lname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_lname));
    list_textview.add(textView_birthdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_birthdate));
    list_textview.add(textView_gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_gender));
    list_textview.add(textView_tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_tel));
    list_textview.add(textView_carefname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_c_fname) );
    list_textview.add(textView_carelname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_c_lname) );
    list_textview.add(textView_careemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_c_email) );
    list_textview.add(textView_caretel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_c_tel) );
    list_textview.add(textView_min = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_glucose_min) );
    list_textview.add(textView_max = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingtv_glucose_max) );

    // layout set event
    for(LinearLayout linearLayout : list_linear){
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // textView set event
    for(TextView textView : list_textview){
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Now I'm got confuse with this other onClick on other LinearLayout work fine without any problem. Only setDate that not first on first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the setBirthDate() like this below:-

You should initiate the  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() first before initialising new DatePickerDialog()

```
public void setBirthDate(){
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month += 1;
                String date = null;
                if (month < 10) {
                    if (day < 10) {
                        date = "0" + day + "/" + "0" + month + "/" + year;
                    } else if (day >= 10) {
                        date = day + "/" + "0" + month + "/" + year;
                    }
                } else if (month >= 10) {
                    if (day < 10) {
                        date = "0" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                    } else if (day >= 10) {
                        date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(SimpleActivity.this, date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView_birthdate.setText(date);
            }
        };

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog( SimpleActivity.this,
                datePickerDialog,
                year, month, day);
        dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.show();
    }
```